# EF-Prism I have two codes (option) for recording

Tags: wpf, database, windows, entity-framework-4.1, prism

Very good!

I have two codes for recording. I do not understand the actual difference in how they work

I'm using Prism(WPF) and EF 4. My code works "well" but is very complex, so I'm doing some tests.
To record orders and released two very well not be real differences in terms of another.

Option 1

In a class lost in space:

```
        using (var db = new MyContexto()) { 
            var empleado = new Empleado (3);
            db.Empleado.Add(empleado);
            int recordsAffected = db.SaveChanges();
            Console.WriteLine(
                "Saved {0} entities to the database, press any key to exit.",
            recordsAffected);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

//I take the class and throw. ¿It used to using the connection is closed then?

Option 2

```
namespace DAL
{
    public class MyContexto : DbContext
    {
    ...
    public MyContexto() : base("CocinaDB"){
        MyContextoInitializer mci = new MyContextoInitializer();
        Database.SetInitializer(mci);
    }
    }

public class MyContextoInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MyContexto>
    {
    ...
        protected override void Seed(MyContexto context)
        {
            context.Empleado.Add(new Empleado(1));
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Any chance more? I have to do two applications one for 15 + - users and one for 150 + -

Thank you very much and best regards.